# What is the name of this control in android?

Tags: android

I was wondering what the name of this control is in android studio and where I can find and use it? (The one that is opened and has all those selectable options.) first I thought it's Expandable List View Item but I don't think it is, unless it's customized or something.
Thank you
(image credits: Converter app by Asif Chowdhury)
[image: pic]

Comment: It is a spinner. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) control.

The page I linked also contains some examples of how to use one.

Answer (score 2):

**Spinners** provide a quick way to select one value from a set. In the default state, a spinner shows its currently selected value. Touching the spinner displays a `dropdown` menu with all other available values, from which the user can select a new one.
You can visit here for demo project (Static list data) [android-spinner-dropdown-example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-spinner-dropdown-example.html) . And [Android Spinner (DropDown List) Example](http://pulse7.net/android/android-spinner-dropdown-list-example/)